# Simple jQuery and AJAX Tutorial Example

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've looked it up and saw several similar posts, but, to be honest, the examples given demonstrating my problem, were too complicated for me to figure out.

I've done a couple of tutorials using plain JavaScript to demonstrate AJAX, and it was all pretty straight forward, with the XMLHttpRequest function, etc.

However, I cannot get jQuery to process AJAX, even with very basic code, such as the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ajax_test_002.html</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("button").click(function() {
                    $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="div1">
      <h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2>
    </div>

    <button>Get External Content</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using jQuery 3.5.1.  My source file, demo_test.txt has only a couple of lines.

In other post, I see something about a header, but, I have no idea where the jQuery/AJAX header is to edit it.

Thanks for your patience with this beginner.

-The CodeSchlocker

Comment: By chance are you trying to run this from `file://` protocol rather than a localhost or remote server? If so browser security restrictions block using ajax

Comment: i tested your code on plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/DbfVdd3Ikv9f7Uwh?open=lib%2Fscript.js and it works Are you sure that jquery.js and demo_test are in the same folder than your html ? You better put the query initialization ($(document).ready ) in the body

Comment: I knew someone was gonna ask that Massimo, but, yes, they are in the same directory, as is the jquery code, as opposed to using a CDN.  I guess I should try it with a different browser.  I created the file with Atom and then opened it in Chrome.  Maybe Chrome is the  culprit.  Ah, Charlietfi, I'll try uploading it to my website and testing it.  I did with the demo file, but not yet with the main file.

Comment: @Massimo, why do you say "better put the query initialization ($(document).ready ) in the body" - given that it won't execute until the DOM is ready, doesn't its position in the document become functionally irrelevant?

Comment: @Nikkorian, yes it is (irrilevant). But from a page design point of view i don't like messing the header part with custom code or initialization etc. I leave it for importing libs or my module, normally, while i leave intialization or page code in the body

Comment: @Massimo, I am an old timer - once upon a time, putting script in the body was frowned upon. Now it's de rigueur. It's hard to keep up with with the changing fashions. So do you have a script block at the very bottom of the BODY with all the first person code?

Comment: @Nikkorian im old fashion too .. with jquery you can put it at beginning of the code too, using $(document).ready(). But there's no absolute rule.

Comment: @CodeSchlocker as you make an AJAX call with $.load, you should put your page on a server and browsing from the http call, otherwise ajax call is not served

Comment: Thanks to all, I finally solved it by moving all files to a server.  I don't know why, but my comments from last night were all deleted.  But, honestly, although I see the effects, I still don't understand why you can't perform an AJAX operation on files in the same PC.